# How I create exe in that I pass parameters in C#.net

Tags: c#

I want to create exe file in that I want to pass parameters in C#.net

for eg: myexe.exe "hello"

pls help

Comment: And what is your question? In a console application, you can access the parameters in your `Main` method using the `args` parameter.

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx

Comment: On Google, I found your [exact same question][1], which is already answered on Code Project. It was right there, between all the others answers I got when I googled for the title of your post.

  [1]: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/244255/How-I-create-exe-in-that-I-pass-parameters-in-Csha

Answer (score 13):

Use command arguments for this :

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You Provided " + args[0]);
        }

    }
```

and now you can execute myexe.exe "hello" and it will print

You Provided hello

Answer (score 6):

to make your app receive parameters

```
static void Main(string [] args)
            {         
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                // the args is the arguments you want to pass to this application
                Application.Run();

            }
```

to call it from a c# application

```
static void CallProcess(string[] args)
        {
            // create a new process
            Process pro= new Process();

            pro.StartInfo.FileName   = "exe path";
            pro.StartInfo.Arguments = args;

            pro.Start();
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

`Main()` method has arguments which will hold your "hello":

```
static int Main(string[] args) 
{
     System.Console.WriteLine(args[0]); //this will output "hello", when you call yourApp.exe "hello"
}
```