# Executable (.exe) using Selenium never launch browser

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, command-line

I am trying to to use *selenium.exe* (actual filename) to open FireFox and execute some stuff. Everyting is working fine if i call the method by a button, for example. But i want to user **selenium *arg*** in command prompt.

As seen in [How I create exe in that I pass parameters in C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157454/how-i-create-exe-in-that-i-pass-parameters-in-c-net) and [How to pass parameters to an exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728896/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-exe) and [Launch Program with Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168612/launch-program-with-parameters) it would seem that a simple `Main(string[] message)` would suffice.

But when i type **selenium "test"** the application does nothing.

I put the *selenium.exe* (actual filename) (leave the other files in *bin\Release*) in C:\ and run it from a prompt.

I found weird that the executable is 10KB, but gecko executable itself is 5,000+KB.

Here is **Program.cs**, that should call the **MyMethod()** method:

```
static void Main(string[] message)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Page title i");
        MyMethod(message[0]);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

And **MyMethod()** that is never called from command line, but works perfectly if called from a Form button:

```
static void MyMethod(string message)
    {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://never.gets.here/");
            //MORE STUFF
    }
```

Comment: *But when i type selenium "test" the application does nothing.* Is `selenium` the name of your actual executable or is that the selenium application you are referencing? Should be `yourApplication.exe test`

Comment: it's the name of the executable. I will update the question. Anyway if i were using the wrong name it would reply "bad command or file name" or something... hehe

Comment: It won't if you actually had a `selenium.exe` in your folder. You need to call your application with the command line. It also quite possible that your MyMethod is blocking the rest of the application from running and displaying your form. If you go to Task Manager, is your program running?

Comment: I run *cmd.exe* and then navigate to C:\ (where i put the *selenium.exe* executable generated in bin\Release) then i type **selenium test**, that don't have a reply and never opens the browser. The prompt just shows **C:\>** again

Comment: Best bet is start adding some logging and wrapping your code in Main with a try/catch to see if it is bombing.